# Seeking the right token filters for my requirements and getting desperate

Tags: lucene, tokenize, lexical-analysis

I'm indexing documents which contain normal text, programming code and other non-linguistic fragments. For reasons which aren't particularly relevant I am trying to tokenise the content into lowercased strings of normal language, and single character symbols.

Thus the input

```
a few words. Cost*count
```

should generate the tokens

```
[a] [few] [words] [.] [cost] [*] [count]
```

Thus far thus extremely straightforward. But I want to handle "compound" words too, because the content can include words like order_date and object-oriented and class.method as well.

I'm following the principle that any of [-], [_] and [.] should be treated as a compound word conjunction rather than a symbol IF they are between two word characters, and should be treated as a separate symbol character if they are adjacent to a space, another symbol character, or the beginning or end of a string. I can handle all of this with a PatternTokenizer, like so:

```
public static final String tokenRgx = "(([A-Za-z0-9]+[-_.])*[A-Za-z0-9]+)|[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]{1}";

protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
  PatternTokenizer src = new PatternTokenizer(Pattern.compile(tokenRgx), 0);
  TokenStream result = new LowerCaseFilter(src);
  return new TokenStreamComponents(src, result);
}
```

This successfully distinguishes between full stops at the end of sentences and full stops in compounds, between hyphens introducing negative numbers and hyphenated words, etc. So in the above analyzer, the input:

```
a few words. class.simple_method_name. dd-mm-yyyy.
```

produces the tokens

```
[a] [few] [words] [.] [class.simple_method_name] [.] [dd-mm-yyyy] [.]
```

We're almost there, but not quite. Finally I want to split the compound terms into their parts RETAINING the trailing hyphen/underscore/stop character in each part. So I think I need to introduce another filter step to my analyzer so that the final set of tokens I end up with is this:

```
[a] [few] [words] [.] [class.] [simple_] [method_] [name] [.] [dd-] [mm-] [yyyy] [.]
```

And this is the piece that I am having trouble with. I presume that some kind of PatternCaptureGroupTokenFilter is required here but I haven't been able to find the right set of expressions to get the exact tokens I want emerging from the analyzer.

I know it must be possible, but I seem to have walked into a regular expression wall that blocks me. I need a flash of insight or a hint, if anyone can offer me one.

Thanks,
T

Edit:
Thanks to @rici for pointing me towards the solution

The string which works (including support for decimal numbers) is:

```
String tokenRegex = "-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))?|[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like it would be easier to do the whole thing in one scan, using a regex like:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_.](?=[A-Za-z0-9]))?|[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]
```

That uses a zero-width forward assertion in order to only add `[-._]` to the preceding word if it is immediately followed by a letter or digit. (Because `(?=…)` is an assertion, it doesn't include the following character in the match.)

To my mind, that won't correctly handle decimal numbers; `-3.14159` will be three tokens rather than a single number token. But it depends on your precise needs.

Comment: Does Lucene's flavor of regex support assertions? I think it is more limited.

Comment: @andrew: it does not, but the tokenizer in the question seems to me to be written in Java.

Comment: Ah - thank you for that insight. I learn something every day. I now want to understand where Lucene uses its native regex flavor and where it uses Java's flavor. I tried your approach - and it works apart from one thing: Lucene discards those periods which are supposed to be tokenized (according to the question) - such as the ones followed by a space - and the one at the end of the sample text.

Comment: @andrewJames: I think the punctuation is being removed later in the tokenisation pipeline. I would have thought that there is a way to suppress that, but I really haven't kept up with Lucene changes over the years.

Comment: ooh, zero-width forward assertion?!?! You've opened up a whole new world for me that I never knew existed.

Comment: @TrevorN: Here it is on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qFxBRn/1), complete with analysis, documentation and cross-references. It's a really nice service if your regex variety is one of the ones they support (see left sidebar and make sure you choose the right option :-).

Comment: Well (hangs head in shame) you've found a bug in the regex I had posted. Decimal numbers I had completely missed. Need to keep the dec point. Probably need to keep a leading minus sign IF followed by  a digit too.